# Unable to use onedrive on any browser on ubuntu

Tags: networking, google-chrome, chromium, browser

I am unable to access OneDrive on ubuntu through any browser.

Microsoft Edge:
[image]

Brave:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

I also tried switching from LAN to mobile hotspot. Still the same. This also used to happen on another LAN at my home. However, sometimes the website works.

Stack trace from dev tools console: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fWuaTZv8iCRnH_mjdPfoSS-MljeKtPWe/view?usp=share_link)

PS:

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 64-bit
GNOME: 3.36.8

Comment: Sorry I can't help with your issue, but I'd ensure you've applied all security fixes & upgrade and check again.  A fully-upgraded 20.04 system has reported itself as 20.04.5 for some time now (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/09/01/ubuntu-20-04-5-lts-released/ *shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded in weeks before that date*)

Comment: No problem here: Ubuntu 22.10, Firefox 108.0.1.